# ERR_SDK_NOT_FOUND: No valid Android SDK root found

Tags: android, mobile, capacitor

I want to start capacitor on mobile phone using `npx cap run android`, but always i'm getting such error this :
[image: 1]

I didn't found helpful solutions. Actually i have android studio and correct ANDROID_SDK_ROOT="path_to_sdk". I hope that i will find help there.

P.S. i use Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

for i added following line at the end of file .bashrc
by `nano ~/.bashrc` command

```
export CAPACITOR_ANDROID_STUDIO_PATH=/home/ubuntu/Android/Sdk
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/home/ubuntu/Android/Sdk 
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/ubuntu/Android/Sdk 
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/home/ubuntu/Android/Sdk
```

after saving run

```
 source ~/.bashrc
```

in terminal restart VS-code and it worked "ubuntu" is my username in above example

Answer (score -1):

Actually i found solution, from project root there wasn't ANROID_SDK_ROOT direction and i just added it there. You can check this using command `echo $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` on Ubuntu

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).